# Australian real estate API (for google maps mashup)

Tags: json, api, google-maps

Had an idea for a Google Maps + Real Estate mashup, and would like to start a pet project.

A.t.m. I'm looking for a source of real estate data. I want to avoid scraping, most preferably something that has an API which returns JSON (preferably) or XML (or anything else that is programmatically parseable really).

The big online portals in the area, http://domain.com.au , http://realestate.com.au & http://realestateview.com.au do not appear to have any API that is publicly exposed. Have I missed something here?

The only site that I have found so far is [Nestoria](http://www.nestoria.co.uk/help/api), however their Australian listings do not appear to be as comprehensive as the sites mentioned above.

Any one know of more sources of data?

Comment: actually there is a realestate.com.au API, you can read about an implementation of it here [http://webtools.realestate.com.au/] and a demo using JS to do a fetch [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saramic/11scr07p/) the general gist of it can be demonstrated with curl `curl 'http://services.realestate.com.au/services/listings/search?query=\{"channel":"b‌​uy","filters":\{"replaceProjectWithFirstChild":true,"propertyTypes":\["house"\],"‌​priceRange":\{"minimum":0\}\},"localities":\[\{"subdivision":"NSW","postcode":"22‌​87"\}\]\}'` (just make sure there are no spaces when you cut & paste curl cmd

Comment: @MichaelMilewski have you figured out how to filter by bedrooms per chance? I've tried every permutation of filter { 'min-bedrooms': 4 }, filter { minBeds: 4}, filter { beds { min: 2} } filter { bedrooms { min: 4 }} filter bedrooms { minimum: 4 }} etc etc but to no avail

Comment: @Al. according to the [documentation](http://webtools.realestate.com.au/configuring-widgets-included-via-javascript/) it should be 'minimum-bedrooms'  but that does not seem to work for me :( `curl 'http://services.realestate.com.au/services/listings/search?query=\{"channel":"buy","filters":\{"minimum-bedrooms":"4","propertyTypes":\["house"\]\}\}' | ruby -e 'require "JSON"; puts JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse($<.read))' | grep 'bedrooms.: \d'`

Comment: Domain provides publicly accessible APIs to get started for free. Check out their [developer portal](https://developer.domain.com.au/docs/introduction).

Comment: @MichaelMilewski does that API still work for real estate? It seems that they are using graphql to drive their site now?

Comment: not sure @Greg but the `curl -L 'http://services.realestate.com.au/services/listings/search?query=\{"channel":"buy","filters":\{"replaceProjectWithFirstChild":true,"propertyTypes":\["house"\],"​priceRange":\{"minimum":0\}\},"localities":\[\{"subdivision":"NSW","postcode":"2287"\}\]\}'` and the https://jsfiddle.net/saramic/11scr07p/ still seem to work on Mon 4th Jan 2021

Answer (score 4):

If you're wanting something for free, scraping is really your only option.  You can be sure that anyone who DOES provide the data for free is also probably scraping it from the domain.com.au and realestate.com.au's of the world.   ([this](http://www.smh.com.au/small-business/sites-web-scraping-prompts-threat-of-legal-action-20100514-v2gf.html) is usually the outcome)

You may have some luck if you're willing to spend a few bucks though.   The below sites offer very comprehensive data sets, however I imagine it won't be cheap.

- apm.com.au
- residex.com.au
- rpdata.net.au

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately as this is just a pet project (no commercial interest or application), I'd prefer something that is beer as in beer. I have a feeling that Australia is way behind real estate in the US in terms of APIs.

Comment: Oh, and welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

Only thing I've found has been a monthly summary of Australian capital cities real estate markets in [json from RPData](http://www.rpdata.com/data/asx.json?_=1332906118776).